# MSMQ read error (access denied)

Tags: c#, .net, msmq

I create a queue on my local machine in some other process as follows:

```
MessageQueue.Create(@".\private$\sampleQueue");
```

And in my reader process, I attach to it as follows:

```
var queue = new MessageQueue(@".\private$\sampleQueue");
```

When I try to do `queue.Peek()`, I get an access denied exception. I'm not on a domain, this is just my local workgroup computer. Any ideas?

Comment: I ran into this situation. Amazingly, once I read the queue's statistics using the Computer Management window, all was fine again.

Answer (score 3):

MSMQ uses different protocols for it's work:

- Pushing information (sending messages) uses **MSMQ** protocol.
- Pulling information (receiving messages, getting properties, etc) using **RPC** protocol.

If it is not a simple permissions issue (which it is very likely to be) then you need this blog post:

Understanding how MSMQ security blocks RPC traffic
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johnbreakwell/archive/2010/03/24/understanding-how-msmq-security-blocks-rpc-traffic.aspx

Cheers
John

Answer (score 2):

If you r-click on the queue in Computer Management and select properties, do you have the appropriate permissions set on the Security tab?

Comment: I'll check shortly, but I'd like to note that the other process, the one which creates the queue, is also able to send a message. The reader process, meanwhile, is running as a windows service.

Answer (score 2):

The credentials used by the process that creates the queue must be different from the credentials of the process used to read the queue.  If that is the way it must be, then you will need to specifically grant the needed read permissions on the queue after you create it.

Comment: I've granted the queue full permission and still nothing, so I'm going to check out the link John gave me later today.